# Combinatorics/Permuation question - Am I overcounting? (Verify my answer)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There is a problem on a recent test of mine and i am wanting to know now rather than later how i did on the question.

The question was: How many variations can a 11 digit number have, consisting of numbers of 0-9, and knowing that 0 cannot be on the first digit. Also allowing only 2 repetitions of the same number.

My thoughts on it were that you could solve it by:

$$C(9,1)\times(10!) + C(9,1)\times\frac{10!}{2!}$$

where the first part is simply that the repetition would occur with the first digit, and one of the digits with the next 10 digits. The second part was that, the first digit would not have repetition with the next 10 digits, where a repetition of 2 digits would occur in the last 10 digits of the 11 digit number. I think i am over counting, in that, there may be a situation where there would be 3 digits of the same.

I am unsure if i did this correctly or incorrectly.

Comment: The Q seems to asking for "at most 2 repetitions of a digit". That's any number of digits repeating, but repeating at most twice. 11220045456 is a valid answer, but that's not what your solution is answering.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as stated is not clear. I will assume that you mean that we must use **all** the digits from $0$ to $9$, using one of them exactly twice. So each of the others is used exactly once.

The first digit can be chosen in $9$ ways.

Either the first digit  occurs (i) twice or (ii) it doesn't.

(i) If it occurs twice, then for the rest of the number any of the $10!$ permutations of the set of digits will work.

(ii) If the first digit occurs only once, the digit that occurs twice can be chosen in $9$ ways. The locations **where** the repeat is can be chosen in $\binom{10}{2}$ ways. And now the rest can be filled in $8!$ ways.

We get a total of
$$9\left(10! +(9)\binom{10}{2}(8!)                     \right).$$

This seems to be essentially what you have done, with a small difference that makes no difference in the analysis of Case (ii).